# wrong value from atan2 function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, mathematica

I am trying to calculate the angle between two latitudes and longitudes but I am getting wrong result of `atan2(X,Y)` when used on Excel.

```
β = atan2(X,Y) = atan2(0.05967668696, -0.00681261948)
```

It should be 1.68radian (96.51°) but on excel it is showing -0.113666736 (-6.512624235°)

```
β = atan2(X,Y),
```

where, X and Y are two quantities and can be calculated as:

- X = `cos θb * sin ∆L`
- Y = `cos θa * sin θb – sin θa * cos θb * cos ∆L`

  Latitude/Longitude(1): (Lat1,Lon1)= 39.099912, -94.581213

  Latitude/Longitude(2): (Lat2,Lon2)= 38.627089, -90.200203

  ```
  ‘L’            be the longitude,
  ‘∆L=lon2-lon1’ be the difference of longitude,
  ‘θ’            be latitude,
  ‘β‘            be Bearing
  ```

Comment: Not sure if you're aware, but there is a [mathematica.se](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) - also my `atan2()` is giving me -0.11367 - so you're converting it to degrees, which you didn't indicate.

Comment: yes you are right, I am converting it in degree after using atan2(x,y)..

Comment: that's the same formula I am using

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that excel uses the function Atan2(**y**,**x**) rather than (x, y). In C, Atan2 uses parameters (**x**, **y**) which will give you the answer you expected. Just switch your parameters.

A good six years too late on the answer, but hopefully someone finds this useful lol.

Comment: Thank you for pointing for this!! I was going crazy trying to figure out why all the programming languages kept giving me the same result yet Excel + Google Sheets weren't

Answer (score 0):

1. There is nothing wrong with `atan2(X,Y)` function in Excel: the point you have specified '(0.05967668696, -0.00681261948)' lies in the fourth quadrant, i.e. its angle is really '-6.51°'.
2. But if you want calculate an 'absolute' value of angle between two geographical points, you should use and absolute difference between coordinates:

   ```
     β=ATAN2(ABS(0.05967668696), ABS(-0.00681261948))
   ```
3. Bear in mind that if this calculation is on a sphere (Earth), it is an approximation because of circular triangle. It is OK for small angles.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Excel's ATAN2 is (Y,X) not (X, Y). Look at @Chance McQueens answer.

Comment: You are not right. Definition in Excel help is ATAN2(x_num,y_num). X is size on abscissa, Y on ordinate. You must differ X and Y coordinates.
Try this in excel =ATAN2(0,5;0,865)*(180/3,14) (this is a right-angled triangle, half of equilateral triangle with one leg (y) =SQRT(3)/2, other leg (x) = 0.5 and hypotenuse =1. 
The result is 60 degrees, not 30.